# wpa_supplicant loops between GROUP_HANDSHAKE and COMPLETED: Intel Wifi 5100 & Belkin

Tags: wireless-networking, ubuntu-10.10, wpa-supplicant

I'm using Ubuntu Studio 10.10 x64. I want to get wireless networking going manually. My wireless networking works successfully in Windows 7 x64.

I've also posted this question at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1630949, and some information is only on that post due to the size limits of Super User questions.

I can get wireless working successfully without encryption but when I try and use WPA-PSK, wpa_supplicant gets stuck in a loop between GROUP_HANDSHAKE and COMPLETED, as shown in the log attached to [the Ubuntu forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1630949).

I've been working mostly off the instructions in this post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=571188

My laptop is a Dell Studio 1537. It has an Intel Wifi 5100. I'm connecting to a F5D7633-4 router running F5D7633-4Av1_UK_1.00.010 firmware, which is the latest version of the firmware I can find. When I set up WPA, it uses encryption technique TPIK.

The other generic information is provided in [the Ubuntu forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1630949).

My wpa_supplicant.conf file is (I've also tried with the commented lines uncommented).

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="OFEE"
    psk=**big hex string**
#    pairwise=TKIP
#    group=TKIP 
}
```

I've been using this script to try and get wireless enabled - the script worked with the wpa_supplicant line commented out when I had encryption disabled on the router

```
service networking stop
ifconfig wlan0 down
dhclient -r wlan0
wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -dd
ifconfig wlan0 192.168.2.110 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
route add default gw 192.168.2.1
ifconfig wlan0 up
iwconfig wlan0 mode Managed
dhclient wlan0
```

This resulted in the log attached to [the Ubuntu forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1630949)

I'm stumped and have lost a lot of time trying to get things going. Any help would be greatly appreciated.